# angular binding span within custom dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom dropdown like the one below which I use in  a form to create roles. The purpose of the dropdown is to select a css-class to associate with a role. The name of the css-classes are role0, role1, role2.... role9

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
 <li ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" ng-model="roleCss" value="role{{$index}}" name="d-s-r">
   <span class="label role{{$index}}">&nbsp;</span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

how do I bind the value of roleCss, so it saves the correct value (eg. role1) ?

Thanks

Thomas

Comment: model on radio will be boolean unless otherwise specified. Not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have it correct. The only problem is that ng-repeat creates its own scope, so the roleCss you are saving into is in that scope, not your controllers scope. All you need to do is add $parent like this.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
  <li ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">
  <a href="#"><input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.roleCss" value="role{{$index}}" name="d-s-r">
   <span class="label role{{$index}}">&nbsp;</span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```